# Display unique values in group by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use `distinct` keyword in `group by` statement in such a way to display unique values in all groups?

For explaining my question, consider following scenario: I have three tables in SQL Server:

`Tb_Student` which stores basic information of Students:

```
 St_id    St_Name     St_University     St_Faculty
--------------------------------------------------
1001        X             KU               Law
1002        y             KU               IT
1003        z             KPU              IR
```

`Tb_Trainings` which stores information of the trainings:

```
TrainingId TrainingName  StartDate   EndDate     TrainingLocation
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1         SoftSkill      12/02/2017  12/03/2017   Office1
2         SoftSkill      25/02/2016  25/06/2016   Office1
3         CMOA           01/08/2017  01//09/2017  Main Office
```

`Tb_St_Tr` which is an intersection table between `Tb_Student`and `Tb_Trainings` tables and stores participations:

```
st_id      training_id
-----------------------
1001         1
1002         1
1002         2
1003         2
1003         3
```

I need to display training information along number of its **individual** participants. meaning that, those who participated to the training more than once, should note be counted.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT
    t.trainingname,
    t.startdate,
    t.enddate,
    t.traininglocation,
    Count(DISTINCT s.st_id) total
FROM
    tb_students s, tb_trainings t, tb_st_tr tr
WHERE
    s.st_id = tr.st_id
    AND tr.training_id = t.trainingid
GROUP BY
    t.trainingname, t.startdate, t.enddate, t.traininglocation
```

The result is:

```
TrainingId TrainingName  StartDate   EndDate     TrainingLocation     total
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         SoftSkill      12/02/2017  12/03/2017   Office1              2
2         SoftSkill      25/02/2016  25/06/2016   Office1              2
3         CMOA           01/08/2017  01//09/2017  Main Office          1
```

However it counts participants even those who participated more than once . how can I display only individuals ( participants that attended trainings more than once should be counted one time) using 'distinct' keyword or any other way to have following result:

```
TrainingId TrainingName  StartDate   EndDate     TrainingLocation     total
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         SoftSkill      12/02/2017  12/03/2017   Office1              1
2         SoftSkill      25/02/2016  25/06/2016   Office1              1
3         CMOA           01/08/2017  01//09/2017  Main Office          1
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: As far as I can see, only student 1001 has attended any training once, however, 1002 has been to SoftSkill twice (on two different dates) and 1003 has been to two separate training courses (SoftSkill and CMDA). I assume then that the required result would give only 1001 (or is it 1001 and 1003?).

Comment: @russ: no student 1002 and 1003 should be counted but for the first time. the second participation to the trainings is not counted.

Answer (score 0):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  This is the 21st Century.

Second, you do not need to join to the students table to do what you want, so your query can look like this:

```
SELECT t.trainingname, t.startdate, t.enddate, t.traininglocation, 
       Count(DISTINCT tr.st_id) as num_students 
FROM tb_trainings t JOIN
     tb_st_tr tr 
     ON tr.training_id = t.trainingid 
GROUP BY t.trainingname, t.startdate, t.enddate, t.traininglocation ;
```

This should count the number of distinct students for each training *session*.  If you want the distinct number for each "training name", then just aggregate by that:

```
SELECT t.trainingname,
       Count(DISTINCT tr.st_id) as num_students 
FROM tb_trainings t JOIN
     tb_st_tr tr 
     ON tr.training_id = t.trainingid 
GROUP BY t.trainingname;
```

The dates and location are throwing off your calculation.

Comment: It still gives same result.

Comment: @KabirPanahi . . . The second query should not be giving the same result.  At a minimum, the columns are different.